# How do I resize the iOS simulator?

Tags: macos, xcode, development, xcode-simulator

I know that there's Window>Scale>100/75/50% but the scale of the retina iPad simulator is still too big for my screen to be able to test anything.

Is there a way I can scale the size of the iOS simulator smaller than one of the default values? I need it to scale down at least to 25% for my screen size to accommodate the window.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't. I've been an iOS software developer for two years and I haven't been able to find a way do this. I have tried to find solutions to this but came up with nothing. I'd love to be proven wrong, but I'm 99% certain there's no way to do this.

When my screen is too small I use 50% scale window, which is ought to be enough until I hook up my big monitor again at home.

EDIT: As of Xcode 9, you can resize it to any way you want from the corner of the simulator.

Answer (score 10):

You can scale iOS Simulator to desire scale (I tried from .2 to 1.4 ) and it worked for me.

To do this you have to go to `/Library/Preferences` and edit `com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist` file. Edit value for key `SimulatorWindowLastScale` to desire scale.

I tried this on latest version of Mountain Lion (10.8.4) and on the iOS 6.0 Simulator.

Comment: On my setup, using Xcode 5 from the App Store, the fine is located in the path ~/Library/Preferences. Modified it as explained and it worked fine. For me, .4 was the magic number to make the iPad fit properly on my screen.

Comment: I had inconsistent results with the simulator in Xcode 6, but ultimately it does still seem to work. `defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator SimulatorWindowLastScale "0.4"`

Comment: Works perfectly to get iphone 6 plus to fit on my (only) hd screen

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode 6.3 just press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> (25% scale) or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> (33% scale).
Or in Window > Scale

Answer (score 3):

Now It's more flexible with Xcode 9- Simulator. You can pick & drag any corner of simulator to resize it and set it according to your requirement.

Look at this snapshot:

[image]

**Note: With Xcode 9.1+, Simulator scale options are changed.**

**Keyboard short-keys**:

 According to Xcode 9.1+

```
Physical Size       ⌘ 1      command + 1
Pixel Accurate      ⌘ 2      command + 2
```

According to Xcode 9

```
50% Scale           ⌘ 1      command + 1
100% Scale          ⌘ 2      command + 2
200% Scale          ⌘ 3      command + 3
```

**Simulator scale options from Xcode Menu**:

> **Xcode 9.1+:**
>   
>  Menubar  ▶  Window  ▶  "Here, options available change simulator scale" (**Physical Size** & **Pixel Accurate**)

**Pixel Accurate**: Resizes your simulator to actual (Physical) device's pixels, if your mac system display screen size (pixel) supports that much high resolution, else this option will remain disabled.

[image]

> *Xcode 9.0*
>   
> Menubar  ▶  Window  ▶  Scale  ▶  "Here, options available change simulator scale"

[image]

**Using Terminal Command**

Follow these steps to scale simulator using terminal commands

1. Close/Quit simulator. (if open)
2. Open `Terminal` app (using Spotlight search, Press `⌘ + SPACE` to open spotlight search)
3. Copy following text and paste it next to terminal cursor.

`defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator SimulatorWindowLastScale "0.3"`

4. Open 'Simulator' (Run your iOS project using Xcode).

You will find simulator scale update.