# Set a default Scale value for Xcode 7.2.1's iOS Simulator

Tags: xcode, plist, xcode-simulator

I just started an online course for learning Swift using Xcode to develop iOS apps. I'm using Xcode 7.2.1 and 10.11.4 on my Mac Mini Server. I use a 23" monitor. When the simulator window displays while running an application the default scale size is 100% which is really huge for my monitor. I would like to set the default scale to a lower percentage without having to hit keys on the keyboard every time I open a simulator window. I'm sure I will never need to have the scale at 100% because of the size of my monitor. I could not find anything in the Xcode Preferences to change the value. I do not see a Preferences option in the Simulator.

I found [How do I resize the iOS simulator?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/62757/how-do-i-resize-the-ios-simulator) with a solution posted by Slipp Thompson in December 2015. I do not have the filename `com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist` or any similarly names plists in `/Library/Preferences` or `~/Library/Preferences`. I also attempted to search the developer documentation but did not find anything.

If this is what I need to do to set the preferences, where can I find sample plist files? Or has this completely changed?

Comment: The simulator is supposed to automatically save the scale of the window. Try running the simulator, changing sizes, then closing it. (You will have to change the scaling individually for every device type, but try just one at first.) If you run `defaults read com.apple.iphonesimulator`, it should give you `SimulatorWindowLastScale-com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.*`, each with a size. If this doesn't work, try setting a value.

Comment: I changed the scale for one of them and then closed Xcode. When I ran my app again the simulator launched at the scale I had set before. I also looked in ~/Library/Preferences and found the plist file. Thanks!

Comment: @0942v8653 please add your comment as an answer and I will uncheck it!